# Why pygame cannot find reference '...' in '__init__.py'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, autocomplete, reference, pygame

I am trying to learn pygame and I have an issue. I use PyCharm and when I start to code, PyCharm cannot find references about pygame (I tried on VScode, it does the same). For exemple, the references 'init', 'quit', 'KEYDOWN', ... My code still work, I can execute it and no problems appear but I don't have the auto completation (this is annoying) and if it cannot find the reference, it might have a problem.

I have pygame installed, I tried to install with .whl files on python.org, with the pip command `pip install pygame`, with the pip command `py -m pip install -U pygame --user`, I tried to see if pygame worked with the command `py -m pygame.examples.aliens` and no problems. I tried to unintall it to re-install it but nothing work. My filename isn't 'pygame.py' and i already tried to see any solutions on youtube, openclassroom, stackoverflow, ... I'm using python 3.8.1 by the way.

If someone could help me, this is really annoying and I could not understand why it does that. Thanks you !

Here's my code test :

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1080, 720))

running = True
while running:

    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
            pygame.quit()

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            print('A key got pressed')
```

And here's some screenshots :

[image: pygame.init() error]
[image: no autocompletation / no suggestion]

[image: code still work]

[image: no references]

Comment: Does it work if you add `from pygame.locals import *`?

Comment: @Nathan No, this import doesn't change the problem.

Comment: Another thing really strange is that, when I open the project, there is no errors and I have the autocompletation but after few minutes, errors come and the autocompletation is not available anymore.

Comment: I don't have a clue... what happens when you run it in the commandline?

Comment: @Nathan When I run it in Pycharm, it uses the cmd, I try with the 'real' cmd and the code is working like it works on PyCharm. It just can not find any references but the code works !

Comment: When I open pycharm, errors appears after the background task, after updating skeletons, python interpreter, python files, ...

Comment: I tried to print what `pygame.init()` does and it says that every module is ok, it shows me (6,0) so this is good ! I tried to reinstalling python, put the path again, update pycharm, mark the directory as source, reinport the project, install pygame by different ways but nothing work ! I can use pygame but it is not normal that it puts errors !

Answer (score 0):

Ironic though, Pygame does have an init() method. I face the same issue while linting. For some reasons the linter can't recognize init() as a method.

Comment: So what can I do to solve this ? I already try to install it again, I reset the path, I put my directory as the mark in pycharm. The most strange is that, when I open the project, no errors appears and everything is fine, but suddenly, it decides to be lazy...

Comment: You can try adding the following to your VSCode settings.json file:
`"python.linting.pylintArgs": [ "--extension-pkg-whitelist=pygame", ]`

Answer (score 0):

open settings and search for "python.linting.pylintArgs"  (no quotes)

then press add item and paste this "--extension-pkg-whitelist=pygame" (no quotes)

it should help for linting

Comment: I tried it, i remove an item that seems to ignore pygame and add this item (on vscode) but it does not work... vscode recognize some expression like init, quit, or locals expression like QUIT, k_a, ... but there are missing modules like the display modules.

Comment: i also have this in the   python.linting.pylintArgs         --disable=C0103     i dont know which one fixed it for me in vscode but one of them did